# Request for new package included for default installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a new ROS package and I want to share with the community but how do I need to do so that anyone could use a command like `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-NEW-PACKAGE` to install it?

Or is it possible to make it available in the ROS default installation?

I think there are some procedures to follow and I should go through some kind of verification of the effectiveness of my new package. Anyone could give me some advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245027/request-for-new-package-included-for-default-installation/) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a link to the [bloom release tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FullGuideToFirstTimeRelease) that you migh find useful.

---

Originally posted by [keshav](https://answers.ros.org/users/28157/keshav/) with karma: 26 on 2016-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1